# How do I use Twitter API with github.com/ChimeraCoder/anaconda?

Tags: go, twitter

I have a web API written Go, I would like to use it to consume the Twitter API and return some properties from a user's timeline.

I have added https://github.com/ChimeraCoder/anaconda to my web API, however I cannot understand from the docs just how to get a timeline for a user.

This is my application currently.

I am trying to use the `FeedHandler` method. I can trigger a search, but when it comes to actually returning a user's timeline, I am stuck.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/ChimeraCoder/anaconda"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type Meta struct {
    Description string     `json:"description"`
    Version     string     `json:"version"`
    Bugs        GitHubLink `json:"bugs"`
}

type GitHubLink struct {
    Url string `json:"url"`
}

type ErrorMessage struct {
    Status  int    `json:"status"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

var (
    consumerKey    = getenv("TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY")
    consumerSecret = getenv("TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET")
)

func getenv(name string) string {
    v := os.Getenv(name)
    if v == "" {
        panic("required environment variable " + name + "is missing")
    }
    return v
}

func main() {

    anaconda.SetConsumerKey(consumerKey)
    anaconda.SetConsumerSecret(consumerSecret)

    r := mux.NewRouter()

    r.HandleFunc("/", HomeHandler)
    r.HandleFunc("/feed/{screenName}", FeedHandler)
    r.HandleFunc("/healthz", HealthzHandler)

    r.NotFoundHandler = http.HandlerFunc(NotFoundHandler)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r))

}

func HomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    meta := Meta{
        Description: "API returning twitter.com posted images",
        Version:     "0.0.0",
        Bugs:        GitHubLink{Url: "https://foo.bar"}}

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(meta)
}

func FeedHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    api := anaconda.NewTwitterApi("", "")

    // vars := mux.Vars(r)

    tweets := api.GetUserTimeline('<users_screen_name>')

    // searchResult, _ := api.
    // for _, tweet := range searchResult.Statuses {
    //  fmt.Println(tweet.Text)
    // }

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Not Implemented Yet")
}

func HealthzHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0")

}

func NotFoundHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
    errorMessage := ErrorMessage{Status: 404, Message: "Request resource does not exist"}

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(errorMessage)
}
```

Comment: Please next time make sure you have created an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): all the code in your example except for the first two non-commented lines of the `FeedHandler` function serve no purpose in demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass in the user's screen name as a property on `url.Values{}`

```
func FeedHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    api := anaconda.NewTwitterApi("", "")

    v := url.Values{}
    v.Set("screen_name", "some_user_name")

    searchResult, _ := api.GetUserTimeline(v)

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(searchResult)
}
```